# Instance creation for private functions in a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does the below code create multiple instances of function fun1 when multiple instance of tempobj are created?. I know that separate instances of fun2 are created for each object. I need to know if the same will happen for fun1 too.

```
function tempobj(){
 var fun1 = function(){ 
  //do something;
 }
 this.fun2 = function(){
  //do something;
  }
}
var obj1 = new tempobj();
var obj2 = new tempobj();
var obj3 = new tempobj();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes , you are defining the fun1 each time you create an object.

Comment: :how do I get private static functions in javascript. Thanks :)